# Show a text popup in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

In a form I have a label, but the label text exceed the panel bounds, how I can do when the mouse over the label for some time show a popup with the all text?

EDIT: Here the code:

```
public partial class AppMenuItem : UserControl
{
    public string path;

    public string name
    {
        get { return label1.Text; }
    }

    public AppMenuItem(string path, string name)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = name;
        this.path = path;
        pictureBox1.Image = ShortcutsHelper.GetIcon(path);
    }

    private void pinToStartToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TilesHelper.AddTile(this.name, this.path);
    }

    private void label1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.PointToScreen(Point.Empty));
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
            ((AppForm)this.ParentForm).DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            ((AppForm)this.ParentForm).Close();
            ((AppForm)this.ParentForm).textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void label1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new ToolTip().Show(this.name, this.ParentForm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to add a [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx)?

```
var fullText = "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip tt = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
tt.SetToolTip(this.label1, fullText);
```

**EDIT :** You should remove `MouseHover` event, and add tooltip to the label in the constructor:

```
public AppMenuItem(string path, string name)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label1.Text = name;
    this.path = path;
    pictureBox1.Image = ShortcutsHelper.GetIcon(path);
    ToolTip tt = ToolTip();
    tt.SetToolTip(label1, name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all! Work like a charm!

Comment: Wait... How I can show the pop up at the mouse cursor, and allow only one popup?

Comment: @GiulioZausa Windows should take care of dismissing the tooltip once the user moves the cursor away from the label. Since there is only one mouse pointer, the users wouldn't be able to activate more than a single tool tip popup at a time. Is this not what you see?

Comment: @GiulioZausa This is very strange. Could you update the question with the code that you use to create tool tip?

Comment: @GiulioZausa Please see the edit. ToolTip should detect the mouse hover event automatically, and display/dismiss itself as the user moves the mouse pointer over the label.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a [ToolTIp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) object and set the desired text :

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.Label1, this.Label1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

check the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autoellipsis.aspx